# How to set on a new random to x, y when gsap is repeated

Tags: gsap

Hello i use vue3 and gsap
I want to give new x and y whenever gsap repeats.
Repeatdelay works well randomly, but without refresh, x and y are always given the same value.

This is my code.

```
    gsap.set(array.value[i], {
      xPercent: gsap.utils.random(0, 900),
      yPercent: gsap.utils.random(0, 300)
    })
    gsap.to(array.value[i], {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 2,
      duration: 0.3,
      yoyo: true,
      onComplete () {
        gsap.delayedCall(gsap.utils.random(2, 5, 0.1), () => this.restart())
      }
    })
```

I want to set new random values of x and y whenever gsap is repeated.
Is there a good way for me?

Please let me know if you don't have enough explanation.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/eager-frog-numon?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
This is example.
If there is an error, please refresh it.
All I want is to get a new random value every time x and y are repeated like repeatdelay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a new random value for `x` and `y` before the animation gets restarted.

```
const setRandomPosition = item => {
    gsap.set(item, {
        xPercent: gsap.utils.random(0, 900),
        yPercent: gsap.utils.random(0, 300)
    })
}

setRandomPosition(array.value[i]);
gsap.to(array.value[i], {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 2,
    duration: 0.3,
    yoyo: true,
    onComplete(){
        gsap.delayedCall(gsap.utils.random(2, 5, 0.1), () => {
            setRandomPosition(array.value[i]);
            this.restart()
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repeatRefresh` property for a new dynamic value

> Setting repeatRefresh: true causes a repeating tween to invalidate() and re-record its starting/ending values internally on each full iteration (not including yoyo's). This is useful when you use dynamic values (relative, random, or function-based). For example, x: "random(-100, 100)" would get a new random x value on each repeat. duration, delay, and stagger do NOT refresh.

For instance

```js
const randomPostion = () => gsap.utils.random(-10, 10);
    gsap.to(logoRef.current, {
      duration: 1.5,
      yoyo: true,
      repeat: -1,
      translateX() {
        return randomPostion();
      },
      translateY() {
        return randomPostion();
      },
      ease: "sine.inOut",
      repeatRefresh: true,
    });
```

See : https://gsap.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Tween#special-properties